# Function to insert dash after three characters in a string?

Tags: php, html

I have a form in the input=text the user enters a number like 123456 i want to change this to 123-456

How can I put a dash after a certain numbers of characters?

I tried many functions but all of them wants to change or relapse a character and i don't want to change any thing i just want to insert a dash - after three characters in the string.

thank you.

this is the code that takes the number from the user i want to put this number in a function that insert the dash after three character in the sting inserted buy the user

```
<tr>
 <td> <small>RIG CHARGE:</small> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="rch" value="<?php echo $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, 21)->getValue(); ?>"> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you describe what you would expect for: 1234567890

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$string = "123456";
$insertion = "-";
$index = 3;
$result = substr_replace($string, $insertion, $index, 0);
echo $result;
```

Comment: i think, that's not the right answer because: 123456789 -> 123-456789 solution with str_split/implode: 123456789 -> 123-456-789

Comment: thank you i wold like to vote you up put my reputation is not enough

Answer (score 5):

Most of these answers are misreading the question. If the string is say 7 chracters long your solutions won't work.

```
$split = str_split($inputStr, 3);
implode('-', $split);
```

will insert a `-` every 3 characters.

Comment: It's unclear whether the OP wants to insert the character *every* n characters or *after* n characters. +1 for one more possible solution though...

Comment: After re-reading it does seem a little ambiguous. Either way, now there's solutions to both problems. :)

Answer (score 2):

Among the million modes you can find:

```
implode('-', str_split($input, 3));
```

But you can do with basic `substr()`.

Answer (score 1):

The general-purpose string manipulation functions, namely [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), are more than enough to handle this:

```
$value = substr($value, 0, 3).'-'.substr($value, 3);
```

Adding a special function for each possible use case would not really be sane.

Comment: what if $value bigger than 6 chars?

i would prefer this solution:  `implode('-', str_split($value, 3));`

Comment: @KevinHorst: If `$value` is bigger than 6 chars this will still correctly insert one dash after the 3rd character. Whereas the one you propose is not only much less efficient, but it would also insert more than one dash. The OP has definitely not indicated that this is the expected result.

Comment: your solution: 123456789 -> 123-456789
my solution: 123456789 -> 123-456-789

Comment: @KevinHorst: To be fair, the question is unclear. Depends on what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 1):

Heck, why not throw in one more snippet?

```
preg_replace('/^(\d{3})(\d+)$/', '$1-$2', $number)
```

I know, `$problems++` etc...

Answer (score 0):

here is answer -

```
$str='aaabbbccceeefffggghhh';
$ans=format($str);
echo $ans;

function format($str){
$output=''; 
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i=$i+6){
$substr1=substr($str,$i,3);
$substr2=substr($str,$i+3,3);
$output.='-'.$substr1.'-'.$substr2; 
}
$output=substr($output,1,strlen($output));
$output=substr($output,0,strlen($output)-1);
return $output;
}
```

now this will work for any number of characters

Comment: You win the cake for the most convoluted solution.